# When I delete an entry from a table which has foreign keys to others, the corresponding records are not deleted as well

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a table (Entity) from which I delete some entries based on an ID from a different entity in Java.

This table has foreign keys to other tables, let's say the fields are ID1 and ID2.
When I delete with an HQL query the entry with ID, the ones with ID1 and ID2 are still there.
Those entities which have ID1 and ID2 are joined with @ManyToOne(CascadeType.ALL), so I cannot use orphanRemoval = true..

Does anyone have any idea what I should do ?

The Entity class:

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = First.class, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_LINE_HEADER")
private First lineHeader;

@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Second.class, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_LINE_CONTENT")
private Second lineContent;
```

The query:

```
        @Query(value = "" +
        "Delete " +
        "from " +
        "   Entity u " +
        "where " +
        "  u.JobExecutionId = :JobExecution ")
```

Comment: The behavior you describe is what one normally wants.  Cascading deletes make sense from the "one" side to the "many" side, but rarely from the "many" side to the "one" side.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Delete using INNER JOIN with SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16481379/how-to-delete-using-inner-join-with-sql-server)

Comment: Nope, it is not related

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPA delete all entites works strange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37696829/jpa-delete-all-entites-works-strange)

Comment: Bulk delete via JPQL does not trigger a cascade. See question and answer referenced above. Cascading deletes will only be triggered via `entityManager.remove(e)`

Comment: Isn't the answer from Ilya what worked for you? if yes then please accept (and in general upvote if it is a useful answer).

Answer (score 2):

Go to the other side of the relationship (in your case `First` and `Second` class), where you have `@OneToMany` annotation and set the `orphanRemoval` attribute to `true`.

Just like this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "lineHeader", orphanRemoval = true)
```