# Updating and deleting from DB using JpaRepository

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities which are connected with ManyToMany relation:

**User.java**

```
@Id
@Column(name = "user_id", updatable = false, nullable = false, unique = true)
@GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
@GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
private UUID id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "product")
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(name = "products_users",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "product_id")})
private Set<Product> products;

@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd@HH:mm:ss")
@Column(name = "created_on")
@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
private Date createdOn;

@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd@HH:mm:ss")
@Column(name = "modified_on")
@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
private Date modifiedOn;

// construuctors, getter, setter
}
```

**Product .java**

```
@Id
@Column(name = "product_id", updatable = false, nullable = false, unique = true)
@GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
@GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
private UUID id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd@HH:mm:ss")
@Column(name = "created_on")
@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
private Date createdOn;

@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd@HH:mm:ss")
@Column(name = "modified_on")
@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
private Date modifiedOn;

//getters, setters, contructors
}
```

I want to delete data from DB by users UUID. How i write query like this

```
@Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "delete from users where user_id = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    void deleteByUUID(UUID uuid);
```

but it deletes the only row in the users table. I want all the data about this user and his products to be deleted.

And also I don't know how to perform an update of user and it's products correctly.

Comment: how you define Manu-to-many relationship in your model calss.....

Comment: @IstiaqueHossain, I edited the code in question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPA delete all entites works strange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37696829/jpa-delete-all-entites-works-strange)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have all the right set up regarding the cascading:

The problem is that you are triggering a native query. This bypasses all the JPA configuration and cascading altogether. Even if you used a JPQL delete without native, this would still omit all the cascading and JPA config.

Somewhere in your code, you need to fetch the User, using `findOne` for example. After that use the `delete` method. Only then the cascading will work.

Comment: It works, thanks. Don't you know how to perform update of this entities?

Comment: Same thing.. you use findXXX and then simply update java objects

Answer (score 0):

Based on Maciej Kowalski answer

To find by UUID on repository:

```
  Optional<User> findByUUID(UUID uuid);
```

On service to delete:

```
Optional<User> optionalUser = repository.findByUUID(uuid);
        if (optionalUser.isPresent()) {
            User user = optionalUser.get();
            repository.delete(user);
        }
        // here on else you can throw an Exception
```

On service to update:

```
Optional<User> optionalUser = repository.findByUUID(uuid);
        if (optionalUser.isPresent()) {
            User user = optionalUser.get();
            // Make changes here for example user.setName(otherName)
            repository.save(user);
        }
        // here on else you can throw an Exception
```